# Calling a endless Python script from PHP

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, infinite-loop

I have a PHP script that calls a python script. Both running on the same Linux server.

The Python script is running in a "while true" loop. Now when I start the PHP script, it remains in an endless loop and never ends.

If i delete the loop in Python, PHP is running normaly.

PHP:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php 
      shell_exec('sudo python /home/pi/blink.py 1); 
  ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.cleanup()

GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)

def blink(self):
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5);
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(0.5);
        GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)

if  str(sys.argv[1]) is '1':
     blink("")
else:
     GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
```

Edit:
How do I properly start a Python script with an infinite loop using PHP?

Comment: What exactly is your question here?

Comment: @Robert: I guess it is: "How do I properly start a Python script with an infinite loop *using* PHP?".

Comment: you want to stop your loop ?

Comment: Yes i want to start a Python script with an infinit loop. From PHP

Comment: Why you don't add `&` to let it run in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, one option is to include the Linux '&' in your shell_exec() function. This makes the command run in the background, you can't stop it (easily) from within the script though.
Code then becomes (note the '&'):

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <?php 
      shell_exec('sudo python /home/pi/blink.py 1 &'); 
  ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

This makes the script run in the background forever, or at least until the Pi is rebooted.

Comment: Unfortunately, the parameter '&' does not change anything. The PHP script continues in the endless loop.

Comment: Right, perhaps that's because the output should be redirected to /dev/null. So then it becomens 'shell_exec('sudo python /home/pi/blink.py 1 > /dev/null &')'. Does this work?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Robert Diepeveen

> /dev/null &

This is the missing Piece

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
          shell_exec('sudo python /home/pi/blink.py 1 > /dev/null &');
    ?> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exec() — Execute an external program
for more details [php manual][1]
```

Comment: I have tryed the command:
exec('sudo python /home/pi/blink.py 1 &', $output, $return_var); 
but the Result is the same